# Concatenate differently shaped keras layer outputs

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

The keras model is like this:

```
input_x = Input(shape=input_shape)

x=Conv2D(...)(input_x)
...
y_pred1 = Conv2D(...)(x) # shape of (None, 80, 80, 2)
y_pred2 = Dense(...)(x) # shape of (None, 4)

y_merged = Concatenate(...)([y_pred1, y_pred2])


model = Model(input_x, y_merged)
```

`y_pred1` and `y_pred2` are the results I want the model to learn to predict.

But the loss function `fcn1` for the `y_pred1` branch need `y_pred2` prediction results, so I have to concatenate the results of the two branches to get `y_merged`, so that `fcn1` will have access to `y_pred2`.

The problem is, I want to use the `Concatenate` layer to concatenate the `y_pred1 (None, 4)` output with the `y_pred2 (None, 80, 80, 2)` output, but I don't know how to do that.

How can I reshape the `(None, 4)` to `(None, 80, 80, 1)`? For example, by filling the `(None, 80, 80, 1)` with the 4 elements in `y_pred2` and zeros.

Is there any better solutions than using the `Concatenate` layer?

Comment: There's no way to *reshape* it. Perhaps you could settle for some linear projection? Or do you want a trainable non-linear projection -- e.g. a decoder network?

Comment: It depends on your features and what you want to achieve. You could flatten the conv2D layer, to an `(None, 80*80*2)`. You could also broadcast the output of the Dense Layer, to match the dimensionality of the conv2D layer.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq  `(None, 4)` and `(None, 80, 80, 2)` are outputs of two prediction heads in my model, I want to concatenate them, so that the loss function for one prediction head can use `y_pred` from the other prediction head.  So I was thinking maybe I can reshape the `(None,4)` to `(None, 80, 80, 1)`  by filling the `(None, 80, 80, 1)` with the 4 elements in `(None, 4)` and zeros. But I don't know how to do it, or whether there're better solutions.

Comment: @MichaelJanz As I explained above, the two tensors are outputs of two prediction heads in my model, I want the concatenated tensor to be my final model output. Could you help me to broadcast the output of the Dense layer, or do you have any better solutions?

Comment: What are you going to do with the concatenated data? There's a bunch of reasonable ways to do it, but some representations are easier to train.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I edited my question just now, the concatenated data is the prediction results my model will output. The reason I want to do the concatenation is for the loss function calculation.

Comment: If the point is just to calculate the loss directly, you could just calculate with a weighted sum over losses for the y_preds individually, e.g. `loss = 0.02 * loss_fn(y_pred1) + 0.98 * loss_fn(y_pred2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this extracted piece of code could help you:

```
tf.print(condi_input.shape)
# shape is TensorShape([None, 1])
condi_i_casted = tf.expand_dims(condi_input, 2)
tf.print(condi_i_casted.shape)
# shape is TensorShape([None, 1, 1])
broadcasted_val = tf.broadcast_to(condi_i_casted, shape=tf.shape(decoder_outputs))
tf.print(broadcasted_val.shape)
# shape is TensorShape([None, 23, 256])
```

When you want to broadcast a value, first think about what exactly you want to broadcast. In this example, condi_input has `shape(None,1)` and helped me as a condition for my encoder-decoder lstm network. To match all dimensionalities, of the encoder states of the lstm, first I had to use `tf.expand_dims()` to expand the condition value from a shape like `[[1]]` to `[[[1]]]`.

This is what you need to do first. If you have a prediction as a softmax from the dense layers, you might want to use `tf.argmax()` first, so you only have one value, which is way easier to broadcast. However, its also possible with 4 but keep in mind, that the dimensions need to match. You cannot broadcast `shape(None,4)` to `shape(None,6)`, but to `shape(None,8)` since 8 is devidable through 4.

Then you you can use `tf.broadcast()` to broadcast your value into the desired shape. Then you have two shapes, you can concatenate together.
hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the code is like this:

```
input_x = Input(shape=input_shape)
x=Conv2D(...)(input_x)
...
y_pred1 = Conv2D(...)(x) # shape of (None, 80, 80, 2)

y_pred2 = Dense(4)(x) # (None, 4)

# =========transform to concatenate:===========
y_pred2_matrix = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(K.expand_dims(x, -1)))(y_pred2) # (None,4, 1,1)

y_pred2_matrix = ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0,76),(0,79)))(y_pred2_matrix) # (None, 80, 80,1)

y_merged = Concatenate(axis=-1)([y_pred1, y_pred2_matrix]) # (None, 80, 80, 3)
```

The 4 elements of y_pred2 can be indexed as `y_merged[None, :4, 0, 2]`